# How to set border to FloatingActionButton material ui

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I try to set border to FloatingActionButton,
Which props should I use to set border.
iconStyle does not work.
https://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/NgQmve

Also how to disabled hover effect,

```
overlayWhenHovered: {
      backgroundColor: fade(iconColor, 0.4),
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I could get border done with className

```
  <FloatingActionButton className="floating">
    <ContentAdd />
  </FloatingActionButton>
```

In my css file,

```
.floating {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```